# How do I prevent another process from terminating my service?

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I have a Windows service that performs various "jobs" for my application (send emails, create backups, check for my application updates, provide some services...)

Recently some costumers reported problems between using some Internet banking sites and my application.

In searching for solutions, I found reports about a plugin (ActiveX) installed by the Internet banking Web site.

This ActiveX installs a **bizarre** service (GbPlugin, from GAS Tecnologia), that kills suspicious applications based in some idiot heuristic, and my service is a victim!

Now I'm trying to "immunize" my service.

**Are there some ways to restrict the termination of my service to protect it?**

I cannot use the "auto restart" option in the service properties, because I cannot be killed!

Both services are running as LOCALSYSTEM.

Comment: It depends on the rights of your service and theirs. If your service runs as system and their server runs as user, then it should not be able to kill it. But I would contact your bank. Browser plugins installing services doesn't sound good..

Comment: "Browser plugins installing services doesn't sound good": YES, but this is BRAZIL!!! My service is LOCALSYSTEM as the plugin service too!!

Comment: change user for their service for the user, that would not have those rights

Comment: In theory u can deny closing request - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683240.aspx
You should implement then special cases to still close if 1) Windows Shutdown is issued or 2) your application requested to close service and signalled to to the service.  3) still don't know if GAS uses proper Service Manager API or just shots down the process. In latter case perhaps you'd better make DLL Service ?

Comment: Arioch 'The: nice tips... How can I create a DLL service?

Comment: @Arioch'The: I just posted an answer that addresses #1 and #2. `TService` always allows Windows Shutdown, but a Stop can be cancelled manually. There is no such thing as a "DLL Service". You are probably thinking of a Driver Service, which cannot be implemented in Delphi since it does not support Driver development.

Comment: @Remy - a lot of system services are made as DLLs running via SvcHost.exe - i don't think they are drivers

Comment: @Beto i think DLL Service would not help you: i was thinking about rogue service killing you not via Service Manager, but shooting down EXE process. Then i thought about using SvcHost.exe that uses some system service like RPC that is disabled to be shot down. But... there are a dozen of hosts running around, and even if you made such a service - your chances to land in the protected hosts are little.

Comment: Why don't you just kill their service? ;)

Comment: @Marck: I cannot kill their service because is impossible. They created a OS driver to BLOCK process kill. I also cannot disable the service or stop it.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely that service runs as `LOCALSYSTEM` and so can kill anything it likes. So it's extremely unlikely that you can defend against it.

Indeed, a quick websearch throws up some some hits that indicate that the service does indeed run as `LOCALSYSTEM`.

Your only tenable solution is going to involve the other software. Either compel your users to remove it, or work with its developers to find a way to white-list your program.

Comment: I would ask if the service is code-signed. If not, that's the first step. Then contact the plugin authors to recognise the certificate as valid and not be killed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GbPlugin is going through normal SCM procedures to stop services and not just brute-force terminating them, then you have a couple of choices to prevent your service from stopping:

1. set your service's `AllowStop` property to False.
2. in the `OnStop` event, set the `Stopped` parameter to False.

Either approach will also prevent you from stopping your own service under normal consitions.  To work around that, you could write a separate app that uses the Win32 API `ControlService()` function to send a custom command to your service.  Inside your service, have it override the virtual `DoCustomControl()` method to look for that command.  Have it either reset the `AllowStop` property back to True, or set a flag somewhere that the `OnStop` event can look at, then call `Controller(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)` to initiate a normal stop.

Needless to say, this is a bit overkill.  If possible, a better option is to simply contact GAS Tecnologia and ask why your service is being flagged by GbPlugin's heuristics and then change that condition in your service, or else ask them to fix GbPlugin to ignore your service.

Comment: Given that this software purports to target what it deems to be malware, brute force seems pretty likely!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: agreed, but we can only speculate without more info.